# Clarification in Servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

I have a servlet code which maintains the number of times its is accessed.

At a certain point on the doGet method the point where the incrementation is done for number of times accessed that part is synchronized.

Can anyone elaborate why that is done and what are the effects if the synchronization is not done in the doGet method.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FirstAccessed extends HttpServlet{

    private Date first;
    private int count;

    public void init() throws ServletException {

        // Enter the time/date when the server calls this servlet and
        // initialize counter
    first = new Date();
        count = 0;
        return;

    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                               throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/plain");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    int local_count;
    synchronized(this) {
        local_count = ++count;
    }
        out.println("<HTML>");
        out.println("<HEAD><TITLE>First Accessed Servlet</TITLE></HEAD>");
        out.println("<BODY>");
    out.println("This servlet was first loaded by the server at " + first);
    out.println("<br>The current time is " + new Date());
    out.println("<br>");
    out.println("This servlet has been accessed " + local_count + " times.");
        out.println("</BODY></HTML>");
    }



}
```

Comment: FYI: the [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) exists for use-cases like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++` is not an atomic operation. It involves

- reading the current value of `count`,
- incrementing it,
- and reassign the new value to `count`.

If this block was not synchronized, two threads executing the `doGet()` method in parallel could enter into a race condition. For example the two threads might

- read the current value in parallel (both reading 8, for example),
- then increment the value and reassign the new one in parallel.

Instead of going from (for example) 8 to 10, it would thus go from 8 to 9, missing one increment.

The synchronization is also necessary to make sure that the change to `count` made by one thread is made visible to all the other threads reading its value afterwards. Without synchronization, you waould also have risks of missing increments.

Note that, although you don't create and execute threads anywhere in the code, the web container itself creates and executes them. So if two users of your app click on the same link at the same time, their respective request will be handled by two different threads, both calling the `doGet()` method of your servlet concurrently.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have a doubt.If User A access the servlet 2 times and User B access the servlet 2 times .What is the count seen by the individual  users. Is it 2 or 4.

Comment: It depends on when they access the servlet. If the sequence of the requests is A, A, B, B, then A will see 2 for its second request, and B will see 4. If the sequence is A, B, A, B, then A will see 3 for its second request, and B will see 4.

Comment: How can I maintain separate count for separate users?

Comment: Store the count in the HttpSession.

Comment: So until I re-start my servlet container the counts will just be adding for all users right?

Comment: @JBNizet, I know that container creates multiple threads but if the code is synchronized on servlet object which will be only one, then how does multiple requests are served? Is it because only a block of code is synchronized? For every request doGet method will be invoked but the increment block will be executed only after one thread has released lock for the servlet . Is my understanding right? I made some silly mistake in answering this question so deleted it. Is my understanding right now?